# How to correctly get PubKey from PrivateKey in Python

Tags: private-key, public-key, ecdsa

I'm trying to master the basics of cryptography behind ethereum etc, mean very basics. trying to calculate the Pub Key via basic Pub = Priv * Generator Poing G in python, so basically

```
from ecdsa.curves import SECP256k1
from ecdsa.ellipticcurve import Point

g=0x0279be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798
priv = 0x02424ed24a02b71b24db7475a9f877ca886486c0a7cc245235eddd1938222cac


privG = hex(priv * g)
print(privG)
```

and every time I get an incorrect value for the public key. could someone please tell me how to do this correctly in python?